# Lazy timeout resolution Circuit Breaker is throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, timespan, circuit-breaker

Ayende posted [a modification](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/15/lying-as-a-valid-coding-pattern.aspx) to Davy Brion's [circuit breaker](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/05/the-circuit-breaker/), wherein he changed the timeout resolution to a lazy model.

```
private readonly DateTime expiry;

public OpenState(CircuitBreaker outer)
    : base(outer)
{
    expiry = DateTime.UtcNow + outer.timeout;
}

public override void ProtectedCodeIsAboutToBeCalled()
{
    if(DateTime.UtcNow < expiry)
        throw new OpenCircuitException();

    outer.MoveToHalfOpenState();
}
```

However, **the constructor can fail** because a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue.aspx) can quickly overflow the maximum value of a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx). For example, when the circuit breaker’s timeout is the maximum value of a TimeSpan.

> **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was caught**
>
> Message="The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime."
>
> ...
>
> at System.DateTime.op_Addition(DateTime d, TimeSpan t)

How do we avoid this problem and maintain the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do a little bit of math

Determine if **the timeout is greater than the remainder** of the maximum value of a `DateTime` and the current `DateTime`. A maximum `TimeSpan` usually indicates *a functionally infinite timeout* (making this a "one-time" circuit breaker).

```
public OpenState(CircuitBreaker outer)
    : base(outer)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    expiry = outer.Timeout > (DateTime.MaxValue - now) 
        ? DateTime.MaxValue
        : now + outer.Timeout;
}
```